# Proper grammatical form of transition words

Tags: grammar

When using a transition, do I put the semicolon before or after it?
For example, if I'm saying "in fact" is it written

(;in fact,)

or

(,in fact;)
?

Comment: Please edit your question. Place each example on its own separate line. Right now it's indecipherable.

Comment: Example context, please.

Comment: As FumbleFingers notes, this is entirely dependent on context.

Comment: Correct: "Capybaras are mammals; in fact, they are rodents. They live in South America." Also correct:  "Capybaras are mammals. They are rodents, in fact; and they live in South America." These aren't the only correct ways to punctuate my two examples, but they are correct ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That all depends on whether you want it to belong to the sentence before or after the *in fact*. Notice the difference:

> - He never said much; **in fact**, *he never really said anything*.
> - He never said much. *He never said anything*, **in fact**; I didn't like that.

In both cases, the **in fact** indicates further explanation for the *he never said much* and the phrase *he never really said anything* is that further explanation.

I am not sure as to which of the two orders is more frequent. To me, the first one (where *in fact* comes **before** the rest of the sentence) sounds more natural.